# Python - Sort each value in a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each value is a list of objects, and I am trying to sort each of those lists by the 'weight' attribute of the objects.

Everything I've read online talks about sorting the entire dictionary by key or value, whereas I just want to sort each value in the dictionary.

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to be modifying value lists and I'm not sure why.

```
for key in result:
    result[key].sort(key=lambda x: x.weight)
```

Comment: The code you've posted should work. You should include a more complete example, as the issue seems to be with your surrounding code

Comment: weight is probably a string...

Comment: @J.J nope, its definitely an integer as Ive used the weight in several other places successfully. I would post more code but this is used in a project solution and I wouldn't want to give my code to other students

Comment: But you're willing to ask SO for help? -___-; hahaha. Still, if that isn't the issue, then I really can't help more without more info on the data and the actual code.

Comment: @J.J. My entire solution is 700ish lines of code. I'm not asking how to solve my project, I'm just new to python and was wondering if I was making a simple mistake in manipulating dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is, as the same code (with `weight` replaced) works for me. So maybe the problem is `weight`?

```
result = {1: ['ab', 'abc', 'a'], 2: ['bcd', 'b', 'bc'], 3: ['cde', 'cd', 'c']}

for key in result:
    result[key].sort(key=lambda x: len(x))

print(result)
# {1: ['a', 'ab', 'abc'], 2: ['b', 'bc', 'bcd'], 3: ['c', 'cd', 'cde']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comments - there's just simply no way to answer your question without more code, because what you pasted works :/

```
>>> class my_object:
...     def __init__(self,weight): self.weight = weight
... 
>>> a = my_object(1)
>>> b = my_object(2)
>>> c = my_object(3)
>>> d = my_object(4)
>>> my_list = [ c , b, a, d ]
>>> my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.weight)
>>> my_list
[<__main__.my_object instance at 0x7f285035c8c0>, <__main__.my_object instance at 0x7f285035c908>, <__main__.my_object instance at 0x7f285035c878>, <__main__.my_object instance at 0x7f285035c9e0>]
>>> a,b,c,d
(<__main__.my_object instance at 0x7f285035c8c0>, <__main__.my_object instance at 0x7f285035c908>, <__main__.my_object instance at 0x7f285035c878>, <__main__.my_object instance at 0x7f285035c9e0>)
```

Consider putting a bunch of asserts into your code to make sure things are really what you expect them to be :)